# Redirect on selecting a select input

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
</script>

<form action="something?val="+x enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     <label>Select the Playlist:</label>
     <select name="select" id="mySelect">
      <option value="#">----Select-----</option>
      <option value="playlist1">Playlist1</option>
      <option value="playlist2">Playlist2</option>
     </select>
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now i want that when i select playlist1 and press the submit button my page should redirect to something?val=playlist1..But it is redirecting to something?val= ..Value of x is not getting printed there.I cannot find the mistake please help.

Comment: How do you output the playlist? Is it hard-coded? Generated with a server script like PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign id to your form so that it is easier to access thru js, like:

```
...
<form id="myform" action="something" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
...
```

and use [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event handler of select element to change your form's action, such as:

```
var selectEle = document.getElementById("mySelect");
selectEle.onchange = function(event) {
    var selValue = event.target.value,  
    frm = document.getElementById("myform");
    frm.action = (selValue != "#") ? "something?val=" + selValue : "something";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;

//works just like a link
window.location.href = "/somewhere?x=" + x;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you a  little explanation of working flow of your code:

once page load following line will run (i am assuming you write your following js in header).at that time you form is not rendered so value of x is undefined,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
// this is not going to call automatically , when you change value of select box.
    </script>
```

once your form rendered and you change the value of select box you need to call a function to execute above js code to get new value.

and other issue is the way you are using x in html , x is a javascript variable so it can only use  inside a  tag.

```
<form action="something?val="+x enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

For your expected result there is no need of javascript simple html form can do this, use `get` method of form it put your input name with value in url automatically

```
<form action="something" method="get">
     <label>Select the Playlist:</label>
     <select name="val" id="mySelect">
      <option value="#">----Select-----</option>
      <option value="playlist1">Playlist1</option>
      <option value="playlist2">Playlist2</option>
     </select>
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```